# How do I lock specific rows in a tableview through in-app purchases?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, storekit

I have a tableview that requires users to pay in order to access its content. However, the entire tableview is locked. I would like to have, for example, the first two rows unlocked and the third row locked. I also have other tableviews with over 12 rows in them, but just posting this view controller for now. I am feeding in my data through an array, and I already have in-app purchases set up. Here is my current code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TrappingVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var buildingTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var settingsButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

var trapping: [CellObject] = []
var segueIdentifiers = ["a", "b"]


//VIEWDIDLOAD

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //LOAD ARRARYS
    trapping = createBuildArray()

    buildingTableView.delegate = self
    buildingTableView.dataSource = self

    self.buildingTableView.rowHeight = 100.0
    buildingTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    //CELL SEPARATORS
    buildingTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    buildingTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    buildingTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.black

    buildingTableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "TrappingCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TrappingCell")

    settingsButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "Settings")


}

@IBAction func showSettingsClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSettings", sender: self)
}




//CREATE ARRAY OF BASIC LESSONS
func createBuildArray() -> [CellObject]{

    var tempTrapping: [CellObject] = []

    let trapping1 = CellObject(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Yellow"), title: "Below")
    let trapping2 = CellObject(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Yellow"), title: "Side")
    let trapping3 = CellObject(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Yellow"), title: "Above")



    tempTrapping.append(trapping1)
    tempTrapping.append(trapping2)
    tempTrapping.append(trapping3)



    return tempTrapping
}


}






//TABLE

extension TrappingVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return trapping.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let trappings = trapping[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrappingCell") as! TrappingCell

    cell.trappingTitle.text = trappings.title
    cell.trappingImage.image = trappings.image

    if let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "payment") as? Bool{
        if purchased == true{
            cell.lockedImage.isHidden = true
        }else{
            cell.lockedImage.isHidden = false
        }
    }else{
        cell.lockedImage.isHidden = false
    }


    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    return cell

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "payment") as? Bool{
        if purchased == true{
            performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifiers[indexPath.row], sender: self)
        }else{
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UnlockContentVC")

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }else{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UnlockContentVC")

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}

}
```

Comment: You can simply add check on current row to decide either you want to redirect user to next screen or not. For example:
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 {
    moveNext()
} 
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated true)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "payment") as? Bool

    if indexPath.row < 5 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifiers[indexPath.row], sender: self)
    }

    else if purchased == true {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifiers[indexPath.row], sender: self)
    } else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UnlockContentVC")

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```